How do I address error "Error in model[[k]][[2]][[2]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable" in context of Weibull mixed model in merlin in R?
I am trying to model tree diameter distributions from a series of sites using a mixed-effects model. This model assumes that data follow an underlying Weibull distribution. This is all being done using R package merlin.
Function merlin is throwing error Error in model[[k]][[2]][[2]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable.
Below is a minimum reproducible example using dummy data.
# load tidyverse for tibble functionality
library(tidyverse)   

# generate dummy data
dummy_data <- tibble(
   dbh = c(4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3.2, 2.5, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.0, 2.5, 0.5, 1.0, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.2),
   site = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10))
)
    
# Fit the Weibull model using merlin
merlin(dbh ~ site, 
   family = "weibull", 
   data = dummy_data)

Running this code causes function merlin to throw error shown above. How do I address this?

All the examples on the ?merlin help page that use the "weibull" distribution have Surv(a, b) as the response of the model. It looks like that's a part of the model check. Also it looks like the package doesn't do well with tibble rather than data.frame. It checks types after extracting single columns which doesn't work for tibbles. You could file an issue with the package author: https://github.com/RedDoorAnalytics/merlin/issues

Thank you. Using a data frame does not change anything, unfortunately. I passed this data as a data frame to the function and received the same error.

Yes. This particular error is caused by not using Surv() if your formula. But if you fix that, the next problem is caused by using tibbles. There are lots of issues here.
